# How can I do handle a error in a error handling code?

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to do this code:

```
try:
    print(int(number1)*int(number2))
except ValueError:
    print(int(number1)*float(number2))
except ValueError:
    print(float(number1)*float(number1))
except ValueError:
   print(float(number1)*int(number1))
```

But it finds an error before finishing the code.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? `try` block catches the error and `except` block runs when there is an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you need nested try / except:

```
number1 = '123'
number2 = '456.78'
try:
    print(int(number1)*int(number2))
except ValueError:
    try:
        print(int(number1)*float(number2))
    except ValueError:
        try:
            print(float(number1)*float(number1))
        except ValueError:
            print(float(number1)*int(number1))
```

Prints:

```
56183.939999999995
```